# PdfDocument detect page height android

Tags: android, pdf-generation

Using loops I m generating content for pdf document page
and increment downwards using

```
BaseLine = BaseLine + lineSpacing;
```

for (X,Y) positions

Problem :  I m unable to find when should loop break?
i use

```
if (BaseLine > pageHeight) {break;}
```

and start new page
But it sometimes writes beyond pageheight (How do I know? Because I could see cutoff text at end of page)
(I m not using IText)

Is there any better solution for ending a page?

Answer (score 1):

Maintain a variable say private `float currentTopY;` to save the current position of the page

```
private static final float LEFT_MARGIN = 10f;
private static final float PAGE_HEIGHT = 792f;
private static final float PAGE_WIDTH = 595f;
private static final float TOP_BOTTOM_MARGIN = 5f;

private void createPdfPage() throws IOException {
    page = new PDPage();
    document.addPage(page);
    currentTopY = PAGE_HEIGHT - TOP_BOTTOM_MARGIN;
    currentPageNumber = currentPageNumber + 1;
}

private void addNewLine(int numberOfLines) {
    currentTopY = currentTopY - (numberOfLines * NEW_LINE);
}
```

And everytime before adding anything to the pdfdocument make following check:

```
if (currentTopY - TOP_BOTTOM_MARGIN < height) {
        createPdfPage();
}

currentTopY = currentTopY - height;
```

where height is the height of the component(like image etc.) you are adding to the document.

Comment: I m doing the same but it still write pass the height :(

Comment: No error is shown (As its logical error somewhere)  Sorry cant post Original code